# How can I draw custom colors in Cocos2d-x draw function?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am using Cocos 2.2.6 (the latest 2.x release shown on their site). (I have to use 2.x for business purposes)

I know how to draw shapes in opengl and how to color them, but unfortunately what I am trying to do is not working exactly.

I am trying to give color to vertices with glColor3f and glColor4f but they just show up as monochrome. I tried to enable disable material, lighting etc.. nothing worked.. Is there a filter or something? If so how can I disable it so I can use my own colors in a glPush/glPop block. If not, what should I do?

Thanks!

***Update 1:***

```
void Hey::draw()
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor4f(0, 1, 0,1);
    glVertex2f( a.x, a.y );
    glColor4f(0, 1, 0,1);
    glVertex2f( b.x, b.y );
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Could you please post code sample?

Comment: @Unick I updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: How did you init OpenGL? And could you post screenshot of render result?

Comment: I am not initializing it, that is a problem. The game engine does it. Can it be related with some kind of shaders, etc? Because the same code shows colors perfectly on fully custom code without cocos2d-x. What happens is, it doesnt matter if you change the colors, it is monochrome.. In tones of gray-black..

Comment: Did you setup any shaders? It is hard to say where is bug without full code.

Comment: this is the only opengl code. other than that it is default cocos2d-x project. I didnt set any shaders, etc :/

Comment: Maybe you setuped grey-scale filter in iPhone. Try to call glClear with red color, simple to check.

Comment: glClearColor with red showed the red in the background but thats all.. every other thing is still monochrome.

Comment: You can try to get GL_RGBA_MODE (glGet*) or change glSecondaryColor color. Does monochrome color depend of parameters of glColor4f? or it is always the same?

Comment: it depends on the color4f. by the way, game has all the colors when I use engine's regular codes. As soon as I try to draw something my self, whatever I draw becomes colorless.

Comment: Voted up, i hope it helps to find solution.

Comment: Thank you Unick for your time and your vote!